# SYSTEM_DRV (E:) AutoPlay non-stop popups

Tags: windows-7, windows

For some unknown and magical to me reason I keep getting tons of AutoPlay pop-ups in Windows 7 giving me an option to open SYSTEM_DRV (E:), but when I click that option(open) I'm sent to My Computer windows where I don't see E: drive at all.

Would anyone happen to know the possible reason and solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to your Control Panel and type `autoplay` in your search. Click on Change Default settings for media or devices.

[image]

Scroll down to the bottom and see if your drive is listed.  If so, select a default of `Take No Action`.

[image]

Comment: I rebooted my computer before doing this and AutoPlay popups didn't show up, but I still went ahead and set `Take No Action` for my iPhone under Devices. Maybe it was the culprit all along. Thank you very much, kobaltz.